# AngularJS ng-if for $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In an Angularjs Project I'm trying to get an `<a/>` to pnly show if `$scope.page == 'app'`

in my controller `$rootScope.page = 'app'` and so is `$scope.page = 'app'` but when I use the following in my DOM it doesn't show when I'm on that page.

```
<a ng-if="page == 'app'">Show Me</a>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```html
<a ng-if="$root.page == 'app'">Show Me</a>
```

Comment: what is $root here?

Comment: The rootscope. (`$rootScope`)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use ng-if? Why not the following?

`<a ng-show="$root.page == 'app'">Show Me</a>`

Comment: ng-show only set display=none; so html will be included, other will not include html unless condition is true

Comment: You do realise that Display=none does actualy not show anything in the DOM it completely removes the HTML and doesnt load it into the page